# VScode has stopped showing intellisense for curses library in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, curses

VScode has started acting funny lately.

The first time I played around with "windows-curses" ("curses") library in python with vscode, it showed the intellisense of the library. But now, it has stopped showing.

It is pretty odd, because vscode shows the intellisense of other python libraries, such as "time", but for "curses" it doesn't.

What can I do to make vscode show the intellisense for "curses" again?

[image: curses]
[image: time]
[image: no suggestions]

Comment: did you come up with a solution for this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a clue about consequences of this method due to lack of experience with programming.
But I made autocomplete to work with curses.

1. First of all I found *.pyi files in this folder:

*....vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.4.30\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\curses*

and disabled sys.platform check [(I just replaced [*sys.platform != "win32"*] with [*True*]).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMQ9b.png)

2. I did the same with **_curses.pyi** file which is placed here:

*....vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.4.30\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib*

3. Then I created folder "curses" here:

*....vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.4.30\dist\typeshed-fallback\stubs*

and copy-pasted "curses" folder from *...\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib*.

4. Also I copied **_curses.pyi**, renamed it to **curses.pyi** [and placed it here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YULzt.png)

*....vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.4.30\dist\typeshed-fallback\stubs\curses*

[Now vscode shows the intellisense for "curses".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VUrJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve such a problem. But I know why is happening. Intelisense is analyzing the module that are written in python. The issue arises because the module curses is implemented in C. Intelisense is not able to provide sugestions for modules which were written in C. I hope I helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a pyrightconfig.json settings file in the root folder of your workspace and set the pythonPlatform to "Windows"

https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=sample-pyprojecttoml-file

pyrightconfig.json

```
{
    pythonPlatform = "Windows"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ГончаровИван answer worked for me but the only thing needed was:

1. Go to **`__init__.pyi`** file found in **....vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.7.20\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\curses**, and rename `if sys.platform != "win32":` to `if True:`
2. Go to **`curses.pyi`** file found in **....vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.7.20\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib**, and rename `if sys.platform != "win32":` to `if True:`